# Using wildcards with Parameters in vb.net ADO

Tags: sql, vb.net, parameters, ado

I have the following code which works perfectly fine as part of my program:

```
.CommandText = .CommandText & " and [Name] = ?"
```

I then add the parameter using:

```
.Parameters.Append(SearchCom.CreateParameter("@Name", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 100, Name.Text))
```

This works perfectly, but i really want to search for everything containing the value in Name.Text. I searched dozens of articles which say you can do the following, but it always returns 0 results even though there are definilty data matches:

```
.CommandText = .CommandText & " and [Name] like '%' + ? + '%'"
.Parameters.Append(SearchCom.CreateParameter("@Name", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 100, Name.Text))
```

I have now tried the suggestion below, but still the recordset returns 0 results:

```
.CommandText = .CommandText & " and [Name] like ?"
.Parameters.Append(SearchCom.CreateParameter("@Name", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 100, "%" + Name.Text + "%"))
```

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, writing in vb.net using ADODB to connect to a SQL Server 2014 instance.

A SQL Trace of CodingGorilla's suggestion reveals the following SQL runs at runtime. I do not know enough to understand why it is not working!

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM qFormsAndName Where [FormType] Like ''R1%'' and [Name] like @P1 ORDER BY [CurrentStatus], [DateReceived];',N'@P1 char(100)','%JONES%
```

Please can anyone help?

Comment: OK I have resolved this issue for anyone who stumbles across this. You will see that in my .parameters.append i have put a "default" text length of 100. This works for " = Param" queries (for some reason) but does not work for Like queries because the parameter assumes space characters after the text. Like % P1 % where P1 is a parameter, it traces as Like "%JONES                                           %"

Answer (score 0):

I would try a slight variation on that:

```
.CommandText = .CommandText & " and [Name] like ?"
.Parameters.Append(SearchCom.CreateParameter("@Name", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 100, "%" + Name.Text + "%"))
```

This should work, although it's not a direct answer as to why your version of the code does not work.

Comment: This does not work either. I put the name "JONES" in the text box, and there are records in my database such as "EWAN JONES" and "CHARLOTTE JONES", and still the recordset says 0 results. If i change like to = and remove the %'s, i have to put "EWAN JONES" in the textbox, but it does return the correct records.

Comment: CodingGorilla, does it matter that my select query is selecting from a view, not a table? It is only a view in order to pre-define the joins. the full SQL reads: "SELECT * FROM qFormsAndName Where [FormType] Like 'R1%' and [Name] like ? ORDER BY [CurrentStatus], [DateReceived];"

Comment: It should work against either a view *or* a table.  Can you see the final query that it is running via SQL Profiler?

Comment: CodingGorilla, sorry pal, how do i do that? Is it a Visual Studio tool or a MSSQL tool?

Comment: I think i have worked it out. Started a trace, now i am going to run code as all three varieties.

Answer (score 0):

Answer as a comment to the original question, but for anyone who sees this, the text length should be the length of the parameter text, so:
    .Parameters.Append(SearchCom.CreateParameter("@Name", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 100, tbName.Text))

to:
    .Parameters.Append(SearchCom.CreateParameter("@Name", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, tbName.TextLength, tbName.Text))

or:

.Parameters.Append(SearchCom.CreateParameter("@Name", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, len(tbName.Text), tbName.Text))

Answer (score 0):

Rather than customizing the parameter definition based on the input, it would be better to just switch to the more appropriate `varchar` data type, that specifies a variable length string, rather than `char` which specifies a fixed length string:

```
.CommandText = .CommandText & " and [Name] like ?"
.Parameters.Append(SearchCom.CreateParameter("@Name", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, _
    ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 100, "%" + Name.Text + "%"))
```

(Also, if you really are, as you state in your question, using VB.Net, VS 2015 and SQL Server 2014, I'd seriously recommend a switch to using [ADO.Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than old ADO, which dates back to about 2000)